# Calculations that span more than one row in a data frame

Tags: r, time-series

In a typical spreadsheet I am able to create a formula that references a cell on any row.

So let us say I have the following data:

```
a=1:10
b=11:20
c=data.frame(a,b)
```

Which would yield this:

```
    a  b
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
```

So in a spreadsheet I can place in what would be cell `c2` the absolute formula `c$b2*c$a1` and get the number `12`.  Or maybe even something more complex like `ifelse(c$a>5,c$b*c$a[-1]*2,c$b*c$a[-1]` using relative references.

```
    a  b   c
1   1 11  NA
2   2 12  12
3   3 13  26
4   4 14  42
5   5 15  60
6   6 16  80
7   7 17 204
8   8 18 252
9   9 19 304
10 10 20 360
```

I know R is not a spreadsheet, but is there a package or function that would allow me to treat data frames in such a manner or is there something fundamentally wrong with that kind of functionality?  I keep having these issues with functions that require the spanning of more than one record or row.  Almost all the stuff I work with is a time-series if that helps at all.  Is there a document anywhere that explains such functions?  Maybe there is a `?topic` I missed somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you need to complete the offset by excluding the first and last values, then wrap all that in `ifelse`:

```
a = 1:10
b = 11:20
d = data.frame(a,b)
d$c = ifelse(d$a > 5, c(NA, d$b[-1] * d$a[-nrow(d)]) * 2, c(NA, d$b[-1] * d$a[-nrow(d)]))
```

(I choose `d` as a variable name since `c` is a very commonly used function.)

For a tidier answer keep the main calculation out of the `ifelse` and use it only for the multiplier:

```
 d$c = ifelse(d$a > 5, 2, 1) * c(NA, d$b[-1] * d$a[-nrow(d)])
```

Comment: So what does the `[-1]` represent if not -1 record?  And if I want to multiply with two rows up would I do `-2nrow(d)` and forward would be `+nrow(d)`?  I looked up `?nrow` and it does not say anything about this?  How do you know this?

Comment: Negative indices give all other elements excluding those specified. I know this because I read The Introduction to R section 2.7 and the help for ?"[" (or ?Extract).